# Cannot install Horde Imap Client with composer

Tags: composer-php, imap, horde

I try to install Horde/Imap_Client, as documented [here](http://dev.horde.org/imap_client/install.php)

In an empty directory, I create a `composer.json` file with the following content

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.horde.org"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Imap_Client": "*"
    }
}
```

I then download the composer executable and run the installation running the 2 following commands

```sh
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

The download and installation process fails, on both Mac OS X and Ubuntu 14.04. The message I get is

> Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.horde.org PEAR repository
>   from http://pear.horde.org could not be loaded. Your configuration
>   does not allow connection to http://http://pear.horde.org. See
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements
>   could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package pear-pear.horde.org/horde_imap_client could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package
>   name.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>   details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.

Is the Horde/Imap_Client deprecated or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried simply changing it to pear.horde.org?  http://http://pear.horde.org seems like it is adding the http for you?

Comment: I reported this to Horde at https://bugs.horde.org/ticket/14343

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How much more verbose do you want the error?

> Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.horde.org PEAR repository from http://pear.horde.org could not be loaded. Your configuration does not allow connection to http://http://pear.horde.org. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

Composer no longer allows installing packages from insecure sources out of the box. Regrettably the Horde PEAR repository does not support HTTPS at this time, so you can't go that way. The other way however is pretty clear in the documentation, just add this to your `composer.json` file:

```
    "config": {
      "secure-http": false
    }
```

So it looks like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.horde.org"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pear-pear.horde.org/Horde_Imap_Client": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "secure-http": false
    }
}
```

Please do note that this **disables *all* checks for secure communications** completely. So you're opening the doors to install random code on your system via DNS poisoning, MitM attacks, you name them. **The fundamental solution is to bug the Horde PEAR repository maintainers to add an SSL certificate to their repo.**

Comment: Thanks Niels, i was geting crazy it work as a charm,

Comment: The error message is clear but the web page it points too doesn't mention to put that in a "config" section. I was putting it on the root object and obviously it didn't work.

Comment: It's a deeplink to the config docs ;)  And please heed my last paragraph - you're introducing a wide open arbitrary code execution exploit in your system by disabling this option.

Answer (score 2):

Horde recently added support for HTTPS, allowing you to use Composer without the 'secure-http'=false flag.

So you can use the repository:
 https://pear.horde.org